# MVC reading controller data in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult GetKey()
        {
            CacheKey ck = new CacheKey();
            List<string> value = new List<string>();
            value = CacheManager.Instance.GetAllKeys("");
            return View(value);
        }
```

Is there any way to read this value on a button click on View. As soon as I click on a button this value should be displayed on a text field or text area.

Comment: You can't show a View in a text field. Do you want to just return `value`?

Comment: You should show the code that calls this and the view that renders here.  There's not enough information to really help.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle button click and create a GET request in JavaScript:

```html
<!-- The button -->
<button onclick="load()">Load</button>

<!-- The text area -->
<span id="result"></span>
```

The script:

```cs
$.get(
  "/ControllerName/GetKey",
  function(result) {
    document.querySelector("#result").textContent = result;
  }
);
```